# Nginx: recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, vps, ubuntu-18.04

When I upload multiple images at a time my site goes down, and it comes back when the upload is complete. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

**Nginx Error Log:** `2020/03/19 04:04:29 [error] 6#6: *5085 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.165.196, server: iwallpaper.xyz, request: "POST /wp-admin/async-upload.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.26.0.3:9000", host: "iwallpaper.xyz", referrer: "https://iwallpaper.xyz/wp-admin/upload.php"`

```
Server: Nginx (by EasyEngine)
CMS: WordPress (by EasyEngine)
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 x64
Ram: 1024 MB
CPU: 1 vCore
```

PHP Info: https://iwallpaper.xyz/phpinfo.php

Screenshot: [image]